# Returning value from a promise (asyncronously validating a form)

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, asynchronous, es6-promise

It's my first post here and please pardon me for my english. Here's the problem i've encountered: **I am trying to validate user's address when submitting a form using an external API.** My goal is to prevent form from submitting based of an asynchronously defined variable (which is the error). I would like to somehow return a variable from an async function (variable is redefined after a promise-based request to the API). Here is the code:

```
function validateAdress(requestString) {
  callToTheAPIMethod(request).then((res) => {
    let error;
    const obj = res.getDataFromApi ...obj data from async call
    const precision = ...parameters from an API on which i rely in order to set up the error message

    if (obj) {
      switch (precision) {
        case "exact":
          error = "";
          break;
        case "number":
        case "near":
        case "range":
          error = "Adress is incorrect. Please specify house number";
          break;
        case "street":
          error = "Adress is incorrect. Please specify house number";
          break;
        case "other":
        default:
          error = "dress is incorrect. Please specify smth...";
      }
    } 
    $(".address_error").text(error);
     return error;
  });
} 


function validateForm() {
validateAdress(requestString)

if (validateAdress(requestString) return false 
///i get it that i am not able to return the variable directly from this call, only a promise to resolve
/// if error is not empty prevent form from submitting

...some other code validating input fields
}
```

As a result the error variable gets assigned with a text string specifying type of an error and it is added to the DOM. **validateAdress** function is called in some other function which is used to validate a form on a client-side. The problem is that i am trying to prevent the form from submitting if the variable **error** has been assigned with a value. **It seems to me** that it is not possible to do so. If i am trying to return that variable from **validateAdress** functions it is obviously returning undefined...
Unfortunately, i am also not able to use async/await syntax here..
I would highly appreciate if someone can give me a hint how to implement that sort of functionaly or how to access the error variable.

Comment: You are misunderstanding how promise and async works.

Comment: Maybe you will be able to explain your thoughts please.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `preventDefault` on the form submit handler, call the async function, if everything is OK, call the forms `submit` method.

eg..

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const input = document.querySelector('input');

function check(done) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    done(input.value === '1');
  }, 1000);
}

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  check(ok => {
    if (ok) form.submit();
    else console.log('try again.');
  });
});
```

```html
Type 1 into input and press enter, and wait 1 second..

<form>
  <input />
</form>
```

Comment: That you for the answer, will try to implement your approach

Comment: Thank you! I've refactored my code with the callbacks and it works now..